# Does calculating the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix really take $n!$ computations?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, computational-complexity

I was thinking about a $100\times 100$ matrix.   It seems true that it should require $100!$ computations. Because I start with $100$ determinants of $99$ matrices.  Then, $99$ of $88$ and so on. So $100!$ seemed to me right.

I used Google to search for it and saw others on CS saying it, too.  That it would take a computer $100!$ computations of determinants for running time.

Point is, later I thought it's all wrong. You can reduce the number significantly.  If you were to start from the end.   You can count just  the $2\times 2$ determinant and then go up. Now, the $2\times2$ matrices are reusable.  You're gonna use many of them a few times.

I am a bit stuck here.   I am new to matrices so I need someone to clarify it.
Are there really $n!$, or in this case $100!$, determinants to compute or is it really possible to go from the bottom of matrix by computing the $2\times2$ matrices and going up? So that we would have much less than $100!/2$ determinants of $2\times2$ to compute and then much less $3\times3$ and so on?  So will it come out far less than $100!$?

Comment: One definition of determinant of $(a_{ij})$ is $\sum_{\sigma}(-1)^{|\sigma|} a_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}$ where the sum is over all permutations $\sigma$. There are $n!$ such permutations, so it seems the natural definition gives $n!$ terms.

Comment: Have the curiosity to evaluate 100!

Comment: None of you adress the point of my question.   I offered a way to compute from bottom upward then you get many matrices to reused so instead,  you will be computing them only once and then going up. So you saved a lot in this way.   It's not really 100! Cuz many matrices are reused.  And if you dont agree then explain why. Don't just state the computation.  Refute my idea.  Thx

Comment: The number of distinct $k \times k$ submatrices is $\binom{n}{k}^2$.  Therefore the total number is $\Omega(2^n)$.

Comment: Despite your rudeness, you've never once defined "bottom up"... How about an example?

Comment: Please read the Wikipedia article [Dodgson condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation). The process is bottom up as you describe starting by using 2x2 determinants and then 3x3 and so on.

Comment: Thank you Somos.   But I don't think it's exactly what I want.   This is a more sophisticated way of computing. I am not offering anything sophisticated.  I am going with the standard way of computation -except that I wanna reuse matrices.   So for example instead of computing 100!/2 matrices of 2×2 I wanna reuse some matrices of 2×2 a few times.  And so will I do with 3×3 and so on.   Almost every minor matrix can be reused twice. So will I end up 100! Or much less?

Answer (score 4):

Large determinants are never computed by minor expansion, which indeed costs $C.N!$ operations where $C$ is a small constant (there is no reuse). $100!$ elementary operations takes much longer than the lifetime of the universe (I tried it).

Fortunately, Gaussian elimination comes to the rescue and only requires $C.N^3$ operations. $100^3$ is nothing.

Comment: You don't adress the question.   I don't really care how it is solved nor do I ever tried solving 100 × 100 which is of corse an incomprehensible number.  I did ask though if its indeed 100!  in the way I compute it. Or is it possible to go in a reverse way where some 2×2 would be reused.    You say they aren't  but you don't explain.   Please expand upon this point. I want to understand if it's possible to go from bottom up and reusing many same matrices twice and saving the computation time. Thx

Comment: @bengy: you don't understand. The standard formula as a sum of products or the recursive formula based on minors have $N!$ terms, that's it. And Gaussian elimination achieves so much reuse that it reduces the number of operations to $N^3$.

Comment: I do understand perfectly.  But you keep on adressing something else. I know what you say. And it's a good idea the gaussian elimination and all the other ideas you said are very nice and informative.    But please,  I have a philosophical question.  That's it.  I am not asking you ' what's the best way to find a determant' I ask a very specific question.    Can the minor matrices be reused?  Going from bottom to top. In the primitive way of computing determants.  Should ithe really still be n!  or my idea would reduce it significantly due to the reuse of small matrices inside the big ones.

Comment: @bengy: for the last time: if you use the standard formula, $N!$. If you accept reuse and modify the formula, you end up performing Gauss.

Comment: It's really funny.  But if you forcefully trying to avoid answering my question then that's your choice.   I told you very clearly that I got your point.  And I am still asking very specific yet different question.   You say , if we accept reuse then we get a much better one -that's it a gaussian elimination.  That's a valid point.  I never said I don't agree with you.  I just want a specific clarification in case that I don't want to use a gaussian elimination.  Suppose I am a stupid person.   Now I am asking a specific question.   Can going in a reverse way save for me computation? By reusin